# Access element's id after for loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, onclick

I am using .get() to build a list of seasons. When I do this, I am appending `<li><a>` to my `<ul>` element. After it's been loaded, I want to access the `<a>` elements to return their ids, onclick. However, when I try this, I am not able to access these elements onclick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      var org = localStorage.getItem("org");
      var key = localStorage.getItem("key");
      var user = localStorage.getItem("user");
      $.get('https://domain.com/App/GetSeasons/?user='+user+'&key='+key+'&org='+org, function(xml){
            var seasons = $.xml2json(xml);
            for (i=0; i<=seasons.Season.length; i++){
            var seasonName = seasons.Season[i].name;
            var SeasonID = seasons.Season[i].id;
            $("#seasonlist").append("<li><a href='#' id="+SeasonID+">" + seasonName + "<span class=pull-right>></span></a></li>");
            }
            });
      });
    </script>
<script>
      $("#seasonlist > li > a").click(function(){
                             var test = $(this).attr("id");
                                      console.log(test);
                                      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delegation for dynamically added element:

```
$('#seasonlist').on("click", 'li > a', function () {
    var test = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(test);
});
```

Check [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.on` -

```
 $(document).on('click',"#seasonlist > li > a",function(){
     var test = $(this).attr("id");
     console.log(test);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to a parent element using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and pass the selector as an argument. This works for dynamically added elements as well...

```
 $("#seasonlist").on('click', 'li > a', function(){
      var test = $(this).attr("id");
      console.log(test);
 });
```